# Select row with MAX value if conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Pandas in Python and having a spot of trouble.  I have a dataframe with an index and 2 columns: "VIFFactor" and "features".

I am trying to return the "feature" record from my dataframe that has the maximum value in "VIFFactor" PROVIDED the number is over 5.

Here's my code:

I have tried to replace idsmax with max and got "cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]".

```py
vif3 = vif_test.loc[(vif_test['VIFFactor'] >= 5) & (vif_test['VIFFactor'].idxmax()), 'features']
```

So for example, from the below, I would like to return HadCampaign because it is the highest record and over 5 but I am currently getting nothing:

```
    VIFFactor   features
2   12.028754355028974  HadCampaign
22  11.98926492333954   DiscountedPrice
29  5.460195615389739   RatingsReceivedRank
30  4.59851607313422    SortOrder
19  3.0681452496804833  PreferredPartnerBadge
9   3.0554578279939815  PerkCustomerDropService
28  2.735597253984768   RatingsReceived
26  2.263922204962396   PriceRank
```

Comment: What should happen if all of the numbers in `VIFFactor` are less than 5? Could you simplify this requirement to "return the `features` record with the highest `VIFFactor`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work you should look at `max` , your first condition pass a bool and the length is `len(df)`, but `idxmax` will only return the `index` meet the `max` value which is one value , so if you need slice the dataframe , you need pass two condition same length at least

```
 vif3 = vif_test.loc[(vif_test['VIFFactor'] >= 5) & (vif_test['VIFFactor'].max() == vif_test['VIFFactor']), 'features']
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  Worked a treat.  It has been driving me crazy all morning :)  There was just one additional bracket which was out of place in yours (in case anyone else needs to use it): `vif3 = vif_test.loc[(vif_test['VIFFactor'] >= 5) & (vif_test['VIFFactor'].max() == vif_test['VIFFactor']), 'features']`

Comment: @BEN_YO Is it possible to get only the first value which matches max. In case VIFFactor is same as max in multiple cases then all of them come through

Comment: @MahendraSingh then you need idxmax ~

Comment: @BEN_YO whenever I use idxmax along with a condition the result is different

Answer (score 0):

Splitting over two lines might be clearer:

```
vif_test = vif_test[vif_test.VIFFactor > 5].set_index('VIFFactor')
vif3 = vif_test.loc[max(vif_test.index), 'feature']
```

Note: max() may often be faster that index.max(). Testing on a small dataframe:

```
%timeit d.index.max()
34.3 µs ± 447 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

 %timeit max(d.index)
9.43 µs ± 143 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```